# Одинаковый Foreign ключ

Tags: sql

Есть необходимость указывать один и тот же Foreign ключ для множества записей. Сейчас на такое ругается SQL, дескать он должен быть уникальным. Как то можно это исправить ?

Дампы таблиц
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/iRFeUWojl0j8zA

Запрос, который вызывает ошибку

```
INSERT INTO `keywords` (`id`, `article_id`, `word`, `count`) VALUES
(103, 8, 'Google', 122);
INSERT INTO `keywords` (`id`, `article_id`, `word`, `count`) VALUES
(104, 8, 'Google', 122);
INSERT INTO `keywords` (`id`, `article_id`, `word`, `count`) VALUES
(105, 8, 'Google', 122);
```

Comment: Можно подробнее? Вы пытаетесь от одной таблицы от одного столбца привязаться к нескольким?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Попробую.. у меня 2 таблицы, например. customer и product. product имеет первичный ключ id. customer имеет связь с этим первичным ключем по типу customer.product_id = product.id. Вот когда я делаю несколько INSERT для одного и того же customer.product_id, sql вставляет лишь 1 запись, а на остальные вешает ошибку - "Дубликат бла бла бла" - https://ibb.co/wNDwM9s

Comment: Поместите CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, текст запроса, приводящего к ошибке, и полный текст ошибки в свой вопрос.

Comment: @Akina добавил дамп таблиц в архиве и запросы. Вот на article_id одинаковый в данном случае ругается. Это Foreign

Comment: у вас стоит article_id UNIQUE KEY.....так что дело в этом, а не в FOREIGN

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и правда..Спасибо!